# Why do we see the queries other users have run in SE Data Explorer?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer

Data Explorer is great. But the fact everybody can see what queries everybody runs (in the *recent* tab on the user profile) leaves a strange feeling. Shouldn't this be considered private?

I feel it is a bit in contradiction with some principles of Stack Exchange, where you don't generally have access to things you don't need to know (who upvoted, downvoted, flagged, ...). And I think this is one thing nobody really needs to know, even if it certainly does less harm than knowing who downvoted you.

In fact, it would be like being able to see which questions other users have browsed. I don't see who wants to know this. And if someone really wanted to track this, I would find this behavior a bit creepy, actually.

What value does it add to make this information public?

Comment: So you're proposing that other queries not be visible? How can someone come up with all those queries, if they can't readily use them?

Comment: @TIPS No, just hiding what queries have been run by another user. Basically the "recent" tab on a user profile on Data.SE. Not the queries themselves, of course.

Comment: Well, I don't have a strong feeling about this, so meh in my opinion. Neither downvote nor up vote. However, I think that would contradict how SEDE is built in some way.

Comment: Remember that SEDE doesn't expose what you have voted on, only the amount of times you voted

Comment: @ferrybig Yes, but I'm not talking about votes. What do you mean?

Answer (score 4):

I really see no harm in being able to see what is being run recently by any user. On the network there is not much hidden and that transparency is extended to SEDE. You can find the public data there that is also available on the sites.

Running a query is basically similar to editing a post, or leaving a comment om the site. I can't see how the fact that you got hold of certain data is going to be used against you. Without SEDE you could scrape the site and have similar data.

If you are really concerned about your query executions being associated with you there is an easy way out: Don't login. You can run queries while being anonymous.

Comment: Indeed, you're certainly right, it doesn't do much harm. But I still don't see the value in it either.

Comment: @dim when you propose a change, you should provide a reason why it should happen, since the change would require dev time and effort, not the other way around.

Comment: @TIPS What do you mean? This is not a feature-request. This is a discussion. The question starts with *why*, not *please do this*. I was just wondering.

Comment: Just ignore me @dim, I keep thinking you want it to be removed. :)